# PHP Show image on the browser

Tags: php

- test.php

  ```
  <html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Attachment: <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>

  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
      echo '<a href="showfile.php" target="_blank">'.$name.'</a>';
  }
  ?>
  ```

From the above code, how do I show the images that I uploaded on the showfile.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd also need to pass the uploaded file path to showfile.php unless you have a pattern somehow. Say you decided to use $_GET, the link in your code would be

```
echo '<a href="showfile.php?file=uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'] 
    . ' target="_blank">' . $name . '</a>';
```

In showfile.php you'd have something like this:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];

echo '<img src="uploads/' . $file . '" />';
```